# How stop playing AVPlayer on page leave Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have AVPlayer and when i move to next page, player continues playing and if i add observers they crash if i don't dispose them but i am unable to find a way to handle dispose because ContentView doesn't tell you when it is in background.

Please help ?

Comment: Use the Page's `OnDisappearing` and wire up the event to your custom renderer or dependency service to stop the avplayer and any other clean you need to do.

Comment: yes this way exits but i wanted something more accurate.

Comment: `more accurate`?

Comment: i want to wire it to core features if some exist with contentview, to optimise memory usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xamarin Forms there is no way for a ContentView to find out when it's hosting page is disappearing, unless it gets some help from the Page itself. So how I've achieved this previously is as follows:

**Step 1) Define an OnDisappearing Method in your ContentView**

In your ContentView define a method called OnDisappearing and inside it, do whatever you need to when the view disappears - in your case it sounds like you need to remove your observers and dispose your player. So it would look something like this:

```
public void OnDisappearing()
{
    _playerPositionChangedObserver?.Dispose();
    _player?.Dispose();
}
```

Defining this method in itself won't do anything, you need to actually call it from somewhere - that's where the page comes in...

**Step 2) Override the OnDisappearing method in your page**

The **page** will be told when it's appearing or disappearing and you can use that to then forward on to your other **ContentView**. In the example below MyPage is overriding the OnDisappearing method and then calling that method that I defined on my ContentView in step 1.

```
public class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs page clean-up.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        contentView.OnDisappearing();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying something like that already. I'll let you know if that has worked properly. Thanks !